Problem on calling Flutter code from a Widget Extension
I am now working on create a home widget in IOS with a Flutter project. I have already done most of the part. I only trapped on ask Flutter to resend data to Native side in getTimeline().
I have created a methodChannelManager.swift to manage to method channel.
class MethodChannelManager {
    static let shared: MethodChannelManager = MethodChannelManager()
    private var methodChannel: FlutterMethodChannel?

    func setupChannel(controller: FlutterViewController) {
        methodChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "homeWidget",
                                             binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
        self.handleMethodCall()
    }

    func handleMethodCall() {
        methodChannel?.setMethodCallHandler({ [weak self] (call, result) in
            switch (call.method) {
                case "updateWidget":
                    self?.updateWidget(call: call, result: result)
                default:
                    result(false)
            }
        })
    }

    func handleMethodRequest(){
        methodChannel?.invokeMethod("requestResend", arguments: nil)
    }

}

And in AppDelegate.swift
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
        MethodChannelManager.shared.setupChannel(controller: controller)
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

And in the HomeWidget.swift
class Provider: TimelineProvider {
    //SKIPPED func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry{} 
    //    and func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {} 

    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<SimpleEntry>) -> ()) {
        MethodChannelManager.shared.handleMethodRequest()

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2){
            let data = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: widgetGroupId)
            let nowDate = Date()
            let nextRefresh = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 1, to: nowDate)!
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: nowDate,
                                    name: data?.bool(forKey: "name") ?? false,
                                    age: data?.string(forKey: "inTime")
                                    )
            let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .after(nextRefresh))
            completion(timeline)
        }
    }
}

My target is to reload the widget every hour when in background. Therefore, it will do methodChannel.invokeMethod("updateWidget" , data) when AppLifecycleState.paused.
Also, I have already set setMethodCallHandler of 'requestResend' in main().
Note: 'requestResend' is to ask Flutter to re-pass the data by "updateWidget"
